# Meteor iOS hot code push broken on testflight & production but works from local xcode build

Tags: meteor

Hot code push works fine on a version that I build and load onto a device from xcode, but when I push that version to testflight (or use a previously released version) and subsequently update the production site, hot code push is not triggered. The iOS app just sits there like nothing happened.

Any ideas? I've tried this with/without mdg:reload-on-resume and other packages that alter the behavior of hot code push with no luck.

I've been using Meteor 1.2.1 and recently upgraded to 1.3 beta 11, hoping that the improvements to HCP in that version would solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

When testing app by using the command `meteor run ios-device`, Meteor auto adds the local dev machine address - (i think, correct me if I am wrong). So when submitting to Appstore use the Meteor build command with the server parameter:

```
meteor build /Users/you/Desktop/buildOutput --server https://your_meteor_server_url.com
```

If you find that hot code push stops working while debugging you can add the --mobile-server paramter:

```
meteor run ios-device --mobile-server https://your_meteor_server.com
```